# Parameter count does not match Parameter Value count after minor change

Tags: c#, sql

I changed the code from this

```
public override IDataReader getData(int pageId, string pageName)
{
  try
  {
    return ((IDataReader)(SqlHelper.ExecuteReader(ConnectionStringConnectorPool, GetFullyQualifiedName("PageModuleGetAll"),pageId, pageName)));
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    ExceptionController.WriteExceptionToLog(string.Format("SqlDataProvider.cs/GetPageByIdAndName: pageId:{0}, pageName{1}", pageId, pageName), -2, ex);
    return null;
  }
}
```

To this

```
public override IDataReader getData(string sqlMethod, int pageId, string pageName)
{
  try
  {
    return ((IDataReader)(SqlHelper.ExecuteReader(ConnectionStringConnectorPool, GetFullyQualifiedName(sqlMethod),pageId, pageName)));
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    ExceptionController.WriteExceptionToLog(string.Format("SqlDataProvider.cs/GetPageByIdAndName: pageId:{0}, pageName{1}", pageId, pageName), -2, ex);
    return null;
  }
}
```

Im calling the method like this

```
public List<PageModuleInfo> GetAllPageModules(int pageId, string paneName)
    {
        try
        {
            return Common.Utilities.CBO.FillCollection<PageModuleInfo>(BLL.Data.DataProvider.Instance().getData("PageModuleGetAll", pageId, paneName));
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ExceptionController.WriteExceptionToLog(new Exception("PageModuleController.cs/GetAllPageModules:" + System.Environment.NewLine + ex));
            return null;
        }
    }
```

And now im getting Parameter count does not match Parameter Value count error and im wondering why.

Comment: can you show from where you are calling this method?

Comment: `now im getting Parameter count does not match Parameter Value count error`. Which line?

Comment: Actually that should not be a problem. I can't see anything wrong in your code so far. I actually doubt that the error really occurs in the code calling `getData`, but somewhere within the `getData` method. Have you tried debugging the `getData` method to make sure the real error isn't being masked by an exception occurring in the `catch` block? And did you try what happens in your original code if an exception occurs in the `getData` method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error indicates that you are using a stored procedure, and have supplied more parameter values than there are parameters declared on the stored procedure.

So: check each of the 3 stored procedures, and double-check how many parameters each takes. If one of them does not take *at least 2*, that is the problem. In particular, also check for different versions of the same stored procedure; for example, there could be `dbo.PageModuleGetAll` and `johndev.PageModuleGetAll` - where `johndev.PageModuleGetAll` is the updated version with 2 parameters. But if your application is running in with different identity (integrated security, a dedicated sql account, etc) - then it will still be running `dbo.PageModuleGetAll`

Comment: But how would that procude an error only *after* he changed the actuall SP being called from being hardcoded to being passed in by parameter?

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar well, the `GetFullyQualifiedName` suggests all sorts of options; for example, it could be a different owner/schema, as I already mention; or it could even be in a different database or server, depending on what `GetFullyQualifiedName` does. If the addition of that qualified name makes it resolve to a different copy/version of the stored procedure: there you go - solved

Comment: Obviously that must have been the problem. Then I must tell the OP he didn't test well enough. I know about the problems that could arise in the `GetFullyQualifiedName` method, but the question suggested the problem only came up after he changed from a hardcoded parameter to a parameterized parameter, which was obviously not the case.

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar I didn't say it explicitly, but the obvious next step would be to write out (or unit test) the result of `GetFullyQualifiedName(...)`, to check it is what was expected

Answer (score 0):

Your method is an override of a base class method, so it's likely that the derived classes function signature does not match the base classes signature.

That would give you a 'Parameter Value count error' because the base classes number of parameters is less than the derived class.

Comment: No, that is not a c# compiler error relating to `override`. This is a known ADO.NET exception that relates to a specific scenario.